# Is my SQL insert safe?

Tags: php, sql

Not a problem as such, just been looking at using prepared parameters when inserting into sql database.

Could someone just look at my code and let me know if it is safe. (The use is just people submitting their name, number and address to place a reservation for a product)

**my php:**

```
<?php include 'connectionDetailsOrders.php'; ?>

<?php

if (isset($_POST['fullName'], $_POST['contactPhone'], $_POST['address'], $_POST['product']))
{
    $fullName = $_POST['fullName'];
    $contactPhone = $_POST['contactPhone'];
    $address = $_POST['address'];
    $product = $_POST['product'];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO Orders(FullName, ContactPhone, Address, Paid, Delivered, TrackingNumber, DateCreated, Product) 
            VALUES((?), (?), (?), 1, 1, NULL, GETDATE(), (?))";
    $params = array($fullName, $contactPhone, $address, $product);

    $stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql, $params);
    if ($stmt === false) 
    {
        die( print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }
    else
    {
        header("Location: success.php");
    }
}


?>
```

If someone could just let me know if im the right tracks towards protecting insert that would be very much appreciated.

Comment: if you mean safe against SQL injection than the answer is yes

Comment: But why the brackets around the place holder?

Comment: @Jens i saw it in a stack overflow post somewhere, it works so at least its not breaking it :) are they not supposed to be there?

Comment: no it is not necessary